# Is there anyway to use http proxy in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-proxy

In java we can use http proxy like this:

```
System.setProperty ("proxySet" , "true" );
System.setProperty("proxyHost", "proxy.xxx.com");
System.setProperty("proxyPort", "8080");
System.setProperty("proxyUser", "xxx");
System.setProperty("proxyPassword", "xxx");
```

My nginx can't access internet dircetly, but I have a http proxy server;

So, is there anyway to use http proxy in nginx?